# Selenium C# test script: Input data does not work if I minimize the browser

Tags: c#, selenium

A mileage field in our site has validation can't be null. I enter mileage and click on next in my test script:

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("mileageInput"))).SendKeys("99");
_driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='mileage']/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/a/strong")).Click();
```

When my Firefox browser has focus, then this code works fine. But if I minimize the browser or move to any other application, my script gives the error "Please enter mileage".

The code is not working with a minimized browser. How can I solve this?

Comment: From my experience Selenium does not work when the window is minimized. It can work in the background but if you minimize the window or change the zoom level it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same experience like @IModulo5, that Selenium needs the Browsers to not be minimized , furthermore I made the experience that Internet Explorer needs the focus too. So minimizing the browser won't work. But you can use Selenium RemoteDriver and execute the browsers on a different machine. That way you wouldn't see the browser.

If you don't need the FF Browser, you could also use the PhantomJS Driver.